# Rendering an image instead of its name in a Django page

Tags: django, django-admin, python-2.x

I am trying to display an image instead of its name in my `list_display` page.

I am storing the image in my model's `banner` field. I have made a function that should return the image but I am seeing the string `<img src= ....>` instead of the image.

There is a character varying field is in my model banner.

```
def get_banner_image(obj):
    img = u''

    imgtag = mark_safe(u'<img src="http://www.asdd.com/%s">' % (obj.banner))
    img +=imgtag

    return mark_safe( '%s' % (img) )
```

And in `admin.py`:

```
list_display =(get_banner_image)
```

Comment: Out of (entirely self-serving) interest, why did you mark this as community wiki?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in your `models.py`

```
def get_banner_image(self):
    return u'<img src="http://www.asdd.com/%s" />' % (obj.banner)
get_banner_image.allow_tags = True
```

See [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) for more details (plus an example).

Comment: got the answer  for importing

Comment: It doesn't need to to in models.py any more - this can live in admin.py.